# Got a problem on python when sending a post request

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, html, api

I have made a backend API that works perfect when using POSTMAN for testing the calls.

```
Error: cuenta_actual = post_data.get('cuenta')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2018 18:10:48] "POST /transferencia HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I send data using json language. I have made a custom form for sending data to the backend using ajax but i got a NoneType error when getting the data on the backend. So i think the problem is on my frontend script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var frm = $('#formulario_datos');
frm.submit(function (e) {
    frm.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(frm.serialize());

    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Submission was successful.');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('An error occurred.');
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
});
```

And this is my form on html

```
<form class="text-center border border-light p-5" id="formulario_datos" method="POST" action="transferencia">

    <p class="h4 mb-4">Ingrese los datos</p>
    <input type="text" id="cuenta" name="cuenta" maxlength="20" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Cuenta" required>
    <input type="text" id="beneficiario" maxlength="35" name="beneficiario" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Beneficiario" required>

    <div class="form-row mb-4">
        <div class="col">
            <select class="form-control" id="identificador" name="identificador">
            <option value="V">V</option>
            <option value="J">J</option>
            <option value="E">E</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" id="identidad" name="identidad" class="form-control" placeholder="Identidad" maxlength="12" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" maxlength="35" required><br>
    <input type="text" id="monto" name="monto" class="form-control" placeholder="Monto" maxlength="9" required><br>
  <input type="text" id="concepto" name="concepto" class="form-control" placeholder="Concepto" maxlength="35" required>

    <button class="btn btn-info my-4 btn-block" id="transferir" type="submit">Enviar Pago</button>

</form>
```

Comment: What error? You need to show it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman this error cuenta_actual = post_data.get('cuenta')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2018 18:10:48] "POST /transferencia HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: You don't specify in your question but I presume you created your backend API with Flask. The error you're getting comes from python, for some reason the `post_data` variable is `None`. It's hard to tell how it got that value without looking at your python code.